# findstr DOS Command's multiple string argument

Tags: windows, command-line, findstr

```
findstr /v "black"  File1.txt
```

Above DOS command will display content of 'File1.txt' which are not matching string "black".

How to modify this command , if I need to filter words "black" and "white" ?

Comment: The `findstr` tool is not part of MS-DOS. It comes with Windows (XP+?). I think you mean 'command line tool' instead of 'DOS command'.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

#### How do I filter words "black" and "white"?

The following command will display all lines containing `"black"` **NOR** `"white"`:

```
findstr /v "black white" blackwhite.txt
```

The following command will display all lines containing `"black"` **OR** `"white"`:

```
findstr "black white" blackwhite.txt
```

The following command will display all lines containing **EXACTLY** `"black white`":

```
findstr /c:"black white" blackwhite.txt
```

The following command will display all lines containing `"black"` **AND** `"white"`:

```
findstr "white" blackwhite.txt | findstr "black"
```

Notes:

- When the search string contains multiple words, separated with spaces, then `findstr` will return lines that contain either word (OR).
- A literal search (`/C:string`) will reverse this behaviour and allow searching for a phrase or sentence. A literal search also allow searching for punctuation characters.

Example data file (blackwhite.txt):

```
red
black
white
blue
black white
black and white
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>findstr /v "black white" blackwhite.txt

red
blue

F:\test>findstr "black white" blackwhite.txt
black
white
black white
black and white

F:\test>findstr /c:"black white" blackwhite.txt
black white

F:\test>findstr "white" blackwhite.txt | findstr "black"
black white
black and white
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.

Comment: very interesting.. I guess this would be searching for white AND black `findstr "white" File2.txt | findstr "black"`

Comment: well, since we have NOR,     So there is still a permutation we could consider missing.  NAND.  Another one we could consider missing, is XOR

Comment: @barlop I can't figure out how to do NAND or XOR :/ I know what the output **should** be but how to get there ...

Comment: maybe there isn't a nice quick way,  it'd probably be a batch file checking errorlevel  probably better to use some other tool if doing that, looks like grep can't,. But awk can do quite a bit or of course perl http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/grep-with-logic-operators

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25960/discussion-between-barlop-and-davidpostill).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display all lines with the words "black" or "white" then get rid of the /v in your command.

Try:  findstr white File1.txt
or    findstr black File1.txt
or    findstr "black white" File1.txt

The /V operand will print all lines that DO NOT contain your search string.

Type findstr /? for more info on how to use findstr.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add to this to mention how to use findstr with stdout on Windows for multiple searches.

Here is how to list only network interface names and their ip addresses:

```
ipconfig /all | findstr /i /L /c:"Ethernet" /c:"IPv4"
```

[The Microsoft Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) details each parameter

- `/i` Ignores the case of the characters when searching for the string.
- `/l` Processes search strings literally.
- `/c:<string>`    Uses the specified text as a literal search string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example using a different output method, not just a straight file search. For example check for network port status where `port = 98765` and `status = ESTABLISHED or LISTENING`.

For example this runs a netstat every five seconds, then pipes the netstat output to a FIND (could also use `FINDSTR`), then pipes those results to findstr to filter when the port is in a certain state (in this case `ESTABLISHED or LISTENING`).

```ps
netstat -an 5 | find "98765" | findstr "ESTABLISHED LISTENING"

TCP    192.168.123.456:57349     10.10.12.34:98765 ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.